# OpenCVにおける画像へのホモグラフィー変換の適用

Tags: c++, c++11, opencv

入力画像に対してcv::warpperspectiveTransform()によってホモグラフィー行列を適用したいのですが、
メモリアクセス違反が発生してしまいます。  
[OpenCV warpperspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087241/opencv-warpperspective)を参考に色々試してみましたがどうも上手く行きません。
助言をいただけないでしょうか。

```
cv::Mat src_image = cv::imread("image.png"); // 入力画像

cv::Mat src_corner = cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_32FC2); // 入力画像の四隅
cv::Mat dst_corner = cv::Mat(4, 1, CV_32FC2); // 出力画像の四隅 
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
                src_corner.at<cv::Vec2f>(i*2+j, 0)[0] = src_image.cols * j;
                src_corner.at<cv::Vec2f>(i*2+j, 0)[1] = src_image.rows * i;
        }
}

// ホモグラフィー行列homographyはあらかじめ適切に計算済み

// 入力画像の四隅の点をホモグラフィー変換
cv::perspectiveTransform(src_corner, dst_corner, homography);

// ホモグラフィー変換によって負の座標を持つ点を補正
cv::Mat h;
cv::Rect br;
{
        br = cv::boundingRect(dst_corner);
        cv::Mat offset_mat = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
        offset_mat.at<float>(0, 2) -= br.x;
        offset_mat.at<float>(1, 2) -= br.y;
        h = offset_mat * homography;
}

// ホモグラフィー変換
cv::Mat dst_image;
cv::warpPerspective(src_image, dst_image, h, br.rect);
```

Comment: 自己解決しました。

src_imageの型がCV_8UC1だったのをCV_32FC1に変更し、
dst_imageに予めメモリを確保しておくことで正常に動作しました。

Comment: 解決されてよかったです。自己解決した場合には、回答を自分で書いて後でベストアンサーにしておくと、他の方の参考になると思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

自己解決したので、後でご覧になる方のために残しておきます。

問題は入力画像のデータ型がCV_8UC1だったからで、CV_32FC1に変更したら正常に動作しました。

```
// データ型の変換: CV_8UC1 -> CV_32FC1
cv::Mat src_uchar = cv::imread("image.png"); // 入力画像(CV_8UC1)
cv::Mat src_image;
src_uchar.convertTo(src_image, CV_32FC1);    // 型変換(-> CV_32FC1)
```

また、ホモグラフィー変換後の画像dst_imageに対してメモリを確保しておく必要がありました。
サイズに関しては疑問が残りますが、これで正常に動作しています。

```
// ホモグラフィー変換
cv::Mat dst_image = cv::Mat(br.br().y, br.br().x, CV_32FC1); // メモリの確保
cv::warpPerspective(src_image, dst_image, h, br.rect);
```